# Recursive function returns redundant print statements

Tags: python

I have a simple python application that counts down from 10 to 0.  I have it working except it prints a print message 10 times.
Here is my code:

`CountDown.py`:

```
import sys

import counter


def main():
    A = counter.counter()
    A.counter(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(int(main() or 0))
```

`counter.py`:

```
class counter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
        #return super(counter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        """description of class"""

    def counter(self,a):
        if a == 0:
            print ('BlastOff')
        else:
            print ('T equal:', a)
            a -= 1
            self.counter(a)

        print ('Exiting from countdown(',a,')')
        return 1
```

This is what I'm receiving at the console window.

```
('T equal:', 10)

('T equal:', 9)

('T equal:', 8)

('T equal:', 7)

('T equal:', 6)

('T equal:', 5)

('T equal:', 4)

('T equal:', 3)

('T equal:', 2)

('T equal:', 1)

BlastOff

('Existing from countdown(', 0, ')')

('Existing from countdown(', 0, ')')

('Existing from countdown(', 1, ')')

('Existing from countdown(', 2, ')')

('Existing from countdown(', 3, ')')

('Existing from countdown(', 4, ')')

('Existing from countdown(', 5, ')')

('Existing from countdown(', 6, ')')

('Existing from countdown(', 7, ')')

('Existing from countdown(', 8, ')')

('Existing from countdown(', 9, ')')

Press any key to continue . . .
```

How do I prevent the multiple `'Existing from countdown'`?

Comment: `counter.counter().counter(10)`?! Also, given that `main` will always return `None`, your `sys.exit` makes no sense. To answer your actual question: move that line somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `return` statement to the `else:` clause, you will avoid printing most of the "Exiting" printouts.

```
   else:
        print ('T equal:', a)
        a -= 1
        return self.counter(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

`"('Existing from countdown(', 0, ')')"` will print twice in your program.
once, when a == 0 and again when `a == 1`.

This is because you are setting `a =- 1` before your recursive call, so `1` will be set to `0` before the print.

Instead what you probably want to do is remove `"a-=1"` and call `self.counter(a - 1)` instead, the the value of `a` is not changed in the current scope.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I implemented your recommendation, but I was still seeing the duplicates.  So I tried Rob's recommendation below and it worked well.